# The departed (singular)

Tags: past-participles, participial-adjectives

> DEPARTED
>
> 1. A dead person, especially one who has died recently.
> 2. (used with a pl. verb) Dead persons considered as a group; the dead.
>    https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=departed

[However Garner reads](https://books.google.es/books?id=2xv4CwAAQBAJ&lpg=PA247&dq=%22Really%2C%20the%20whole%20phrase%20should%20be%20rewritten%2C%20perhaps%20by%20making%20it%22&hl=es&pg=PA247#v=onepage&q=%22Really,%20the%20whole%20phrase%20should%20be%20rewritten,%20perhaps%20by%20making%20it%22&f=false)

> *A lock of hair of the dear **departed*** (Really, the whole phrase should be rewritten, perhaps by making it *a lock of hair of a
> departed loved one.*)

Why is **departed** wrong here, unlike, say, the noun *beloved*?

Comment: I don't think it _is_ wrong. The quoted phrase seems to be a correction of _the dearly departed_ (which is wrong). I think Garner suggests rewriting it because it refers to an unspecified deceased person, not a particular one.

Comment: @KateBunting "particular one"? https://oed.com/oed2/00061091 (in _Also (esp. joc.) the dear departed._ "joc." means jocular(ly) https://public.oed.com/how-to-use-the-oed/abbreviations/)

Comment: @KateBunting Fowler reads "With the verb love and in some other
contexts where the meaning is ‘very much’ (
he loved her
dearly; I would dearly like to join you on Friday
), dearly
is usual and dear merely poetic (
The dear-loved peaceful seat
—Byron, 1807)"

Comment: I meant that the phrase _the dear departed_ is usually used when the reader is aware of the context that someone has recently died, so they know who is being referred to. As I interpret it. the phrase quoted by Garner refers to 'a lock of the hair of someone close to them who is now dead', the deceased not having been previously mentioned.

Comment: _Dearly_ is an adverb. The departed person was dear to the mourners, they didn't 'depart in a dear way'.

Answer (score 2):

"departed" or "the dear departed" is correct in this context.

Garner is criticising the "mawkish" style, not the grammar.